# Find the relative weeks between two dates

Tags: pyspark

I have a spark dataframe with 2 columns which represent dates (date1 and date2). I would like to find the relative number of weeks between the two dates (+ 1 week). In order to do that I find the week of each date and subtract the two. date2 is always an earlier date. The largest difference between the dates is at most 1 year so if date2 is from a previous year I need to add 52 to the solution.

I figured out how to do it but my solution seems cumbersome. Here is my solution:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType

def fixWeeks(w):
  if w < 0:
    w = w + 52
  return w

week_filter = udf(fixWeeks,IntegerType())
df_week = df.withColumn("TmpWeek", date_format("date1",'w').cast('int')-date_format("date2",'w').cast('int')+1)
df_week = df_week.withColumn('week',week_filter(df_week.TmpWeek)).drop('TmpWeek')
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same solution? How can I do the same thing in a single function?

Comment: Can't you just compute the difference in days and divide by 7? It would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to provide a small sample input dataframe and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: Good call. I can do the same like this: df_week = df.withColumn('week',ceil(datediff('date1','date2')/7))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way would be to compute the difference between the dates in days using [`pyspark.sql.functions.datediff()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.datediff), divide by 7, and take the ceiling.

For example:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import ceil, datediff
df_week = df.withColumn('week', ceil(datediff('date1','date2')/7))
```